# How do I get s3-upload to depend on (packageZipTarball in Universal)?

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I want to use s3-sbt to upload the result of the package-zip-tarball task (from sbt-native-packager).

Currently, the important part of my `build.sbt` looks like this:

```
mappings in upload := Seq(( ((package-zip-tarball in Universal).value) ,"trailhunger2-1.0.tgz"))

host in upload := "trailhunger.s3.amazonaws.com"

credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".s3credentials")
```

On reload, sbt reports the following:

```
/Users/sarge/Documents/workspaces/TrailHunger/TrailHunger2/build.sbt:56: error: illegal start of simple expression
mappings in upload := Seq(( ((package-zip-tarball in Universal).value) ,"trailhunger2-1.0.tgz"))
                              ^
/Users/sarge/Documents/workspaces/TrailHunger/TrailHunger2/build.sbt:56: error: ')' expected but eof found.
mappings in upload := Seq(( ((package-zip-tarball in Universal).value) ,"trailhunger2-1.0.tgz"))
                                                                                                ^
[error] Error parsing expression.  Ensure that there are no blank lines within a setting.
```

**Update: After @SethTisue's answer my code now reads:**

```
mappings in upload := Seq( ( (packageZipTarball in Universal).value ,"trailhunger2-1.0.tgz") )
```

Sadly, I get:

```
error: not found: value packageZipTarball
mappings in upload := Seq( ( (packageZipTarball in Universal).value ,"trailhunger2-1.0.tgz") )
                              ^
[error] Type error in expression
```

My expectation is that `(packageZipTarball in Universal)` does the same thing as `universal:packageZipTarball` in the console. The `.value` means that I can get the value of the task which is of type java.io.File. That then gets included in a tuple2 along with the string literal "trailhunger2-1.0.tgz". The surrounding Seq then makes a sequence with precisely one element.

I don't see why the value packageZipTarball cannot be found.

I have verified that `show universal:packageZipTarball` returns the file name I expect.

Is s3-sbt too old to support the new sbt 0.13 syntax. Is nesting this in Seq incorrect?

Comment: @SethTisue Thanks for the answer. I double checked and I must have accidentally pressed ] while copying in the error message. There are no square brackets in that section of the build.sbt. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Part 1**

Are you using sbt 0.12 or 0.13?

In sbt 0.12 and earlier versions, keys are `capitalized-like-this` in sbt's interactive mode, but are `capitalizedLikeThis` in build definitions.

In sbt 0.13 `capitalizedLikeThis` is accepted in both contexts. (`capitalized-like-this` is still accepted in interactive mode, but only for backwards compatibility.)

Anyway, regardless of whether you're using 0.12 or 0.13, you need to change `package-zip-tarball` to `packageZipTarball`. The Scala parser thinks the former means `package - zip - tarball`. And `package` is a keyword, which is where the errors you're getting are coming from.

If you're on 0.13, you can forget the whole hyphens thing entirely as a now-irrelevant historical quirk.

**Part 2**

I've found that in order for `packageZipTarball in Universal` to compile, you must add `import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys._` to the top of build.sbt.

The sbt-native-packager readme does have a couple uses of `import` and of explicitly qualified names that begin with `com.typesafe.sbt.packager`, so there was at least a little indication that something like this might be necessary, but maybe the doc ought to call it out more explicitly.

Comment: Ah - I hadn't realised that I needed different syntax in the build.sbt. I also hadn't realized that 0.13 had changed so much. I've upgraded to sbt 0.13.1 and use camelCase but I'm still getting errors. I'll update the question with more because I think the answer, once found, will help others.

Comment: Oh, yay! Now it works. Thank you so much for coming back to the question.